# How can I send user-generated reviews from my site to a Google Places/Business search listing?

Tags: seo, google-places-api, review, microformats

I assist in managing business websites for multiple clients, and we recently discovered a [WordPress plugin](http://www.gowebsolutions.com/wp-customer-reviews/) that claims to send user-generated reviews to a company's Google Places & Google Local Search listing using `hReview` Microformat.

We don't use WordPress, but we'd still like to be able to add a review section to each of our client sites, and have those appear in the business listing that Google provides on search.

I've researched this, but I've read mixed opinions on if Google allows this and to what extent.

1. Is it possible?
2. Is Microformat the only way to go?
3. How often will Google scrape new reviews?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about making it work the other way around?

Embed the google local review form into your site, so users will leave reviews to your listing. And then use a script/plugin/API to implement the Places reviews to your website.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It seems that is as difficult to find a method for as pushing them out directly to a business listing, since [Google no longer uses Google+ pages to manage business accounts](https://www.pelicancommerce.com/how-to-embed-google-reviews-on-your-website/) (see comments below the article).

I honestly think my best hope will be to use a microformat and maybe [link directly to the review form](https://www.webworksofkc.com/blog/get-more-google-business-reviews-by-giving-customers-a-direct-link/) on Google Places.